# How to get data from json Column in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

```
Select replace (( split_part( split_part(json_array_elements(hrstr_json_data::json -> 'name')::varchar2 ,'^' ,2 )::varchar2 ,'#' , 1)      ) , '"' , '')::varchar2   AS name 
from tablename
```

```
"name":["0^John^1^1^1^test1","0^cena^0^5^1^"]
```

I want data in following manner like column name as Name data coming like John,Cena

Comment: Do you want two rows with one column each, or one row with two columns?

Comment: one row with two column

Comment: What if the array has 10 elements? What if there are different number of elements in the array for each row?

Comment: an array can have of any length not define

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the two elements of the array and then use `split_part()` on each of them:

```
select split_part(hrstr_json_data #>> '{name,0}', '^', 2) as name_1, 
       split_part(hrstr_json_data #>> '{name,1}', '^', 2) as name_2
from tablename
```